# Select N preceding rows when column match is true

Tags: window-functions, google-bigquery

I am attempting to select 10 rows preceding any row where the keyPerformanceIndicator column is TRUE (order by descending date/time).  I suspect this is somehow achieved through a window function in combination with a lag function, but to be honest, I'm lost.  Any help is appreciated.  For context, I'm doing this in BigQuery.

**Example dataset**

| date | time | keyPerformanceIndicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:28:00 | TRUE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:27:00 | TRUE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:26:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:25:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:24:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:23:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:22:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:21:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:20:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:19:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:18:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:17:00 | TRUE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:16:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:15:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:14:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:13:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:12:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:11:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:10:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:09:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:08:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:07:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:06:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:05:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:04:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:03:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:02:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:01:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:00:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 14:59:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 14:58:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 14:57:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 14:56:00 | FALSE |

**Anticipated Outcome:**

| date | time | keyPerformanceIndicator |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:28:00 | TRUE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:27:00 | TRUE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:26:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:25:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:24:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:23:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:22:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:21:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:20:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:19:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:18:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:17:00 | TRUE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:16:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:15:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:14:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:13:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:12:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:11:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:10:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:09:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:08:00 | FALSE |
| 3/8/2021 | 15:07:00 | FALSE |

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT *, 
       SUM(keyPerformanceIndicator) OVER (ORDER BY `date`, `time` 
                                          ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING 
                                                   AND CURRENT ROW) is_true_within_10
FROM datatable
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE is_true_within_10
```

If BigQuery does not support implicit convertions then use `SUM(CASE keyPerformanceIndicator WHEN TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` and `WHERE is_true_within_10 > 0`.

Comment: I think I'm getting there.  I was unable to use the implicit conversions and thus had to use the alternative code.  The query began to run but ultimately failed due to the error "Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory."  ... I'm looking into the error more now.

Comment: Here is the current code I'm using.

`WITH
  cte AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(CASE keyPerformanceIndicator
        WHEN TRUE THEN 1
      ELSE
      0
    END
      ) OVER (ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC ROWS BETWEEN 10 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) is_true_within_10
  FROM
    datatable )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  cte
WHERE
  is_true_within_10 > 0
ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC`

Comment: @jbush You have modified the query correctly. The problem with not enough resources is not SQL-related.